# DatTimePicker react-native-community, getting value.getTime is not a function error

Tags: react-native

What I did, `value.getTime is not a function` error seem to come from the onChange

```
<DateTimePicker
      style={{width: '80%', height: 50}}
      testID="dateTimePicker"
      value={values.date}
      mode="datetime"
      is24Hour={true}
      display="default"
      onChange={(date) => {
      setValues({...values, ['date']: date});
      }}/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn out I also need to pass in the `event` as the param on onChange even if it is not used.

```
 onChange={(event, date) => {
 setValues({...values, ['date']: date});
}}
```

Full block:

```
             <DateTimePicker
                style={{width: '80%', height: 50}}
                testID="dateTimePicker"
                value={values.date}
                mode="datetime"
                is24Hour={true}
                display="default"
                onChange={(event, date) => {
                  setValues({...values, ['date']: date});
                }}
              />
```

Note: HotReload will still throw error when add `event` param, will require a Reload/Restart to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try: `value={new Date(values.date)}`
PS: event is also required as the first parameter in onChange

```
onChange={(event, date) => {
 setValues({...values, ['date']: date});
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker/src
In
DatatimePicker.android.js line No:88
DatatimePicker.ios.js line No:69
files change  following
`const timestamp = value.getTime();`
to
`const timestamp = Date.parse(value)`
getTime() is only apply on `New Date()` format

Answer (score 0):

Removed the `maximumDate` prop, that fixed the error for me.